# I am unable to animate a popup during entry, but cannot animate during exit

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

The code below triggers the popup in react, which enters when a user clicks a new order button in the interface. There is a button that whne clicked, the popup exits, but without animating

```
export const NewOrder = () => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

    const newOrder = () => {
        setSelected(!selected);
    };

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className='dashboard-main-neworder' onClick={newOrder}>
                <img alt='New Order' src={addorder}></img>
                <span>New Order</span>
            </div>
            {selected && <NewOrderForm />}
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

This is the animation

```
@keyframes popup {
    0% {
        top: -100%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    70% {
        top: 60%;
    }
    100% {
        top: 50%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

assignment in class is here

```
.popup {
    width: 55rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 999;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    animation: popup ease 0.5s;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's kinda hard to do because when you unmount a component using react it just removes it from the tree, my suggestion would be using something like [react-transition-group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group)